# How can I zoom to certain coordinates in Swift 3 (Xcode 8)?

Tags: ios, swift3, xcode8

I'm trying to zoom to certain location using coordinates.
How can I achieve that?

Comment: Are you talking about a map view? Are you saying you have a lat/long map coordinate and you want to zoom a map to that point? You need to be clearer and more specific.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import UIKit
import MapKit

class HomeViewController: UIViewController, MKMapViewDelegate {

@IBOutlet weak var mapView: MKMapView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    mapView.showsUserLocation = true


    if let userLocation = mapView.userLocation.location {
        //let frontedUserLocation = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(37.7857, -122.4021)
        mapView.centerCoordinate = userLocation.coordinate
        //mapView.centerCoordinate = frontedUserLocation
        //let region = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(frontedUserLocation, 1855, 1855)
        let region = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(userLocation.coordinate, 9484.1, 9484.1)
        mapView.setRegion(region, animated: true)
    }
    mapView.delegate = self
}
```